# Proof that local minimizer of a convex function is also a global minimizer

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, maxima-minima, convex-geometry

**Convex functions in** $\mathbb{R}$

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ be a convex function. Then $f$ possesses side derivatives for all $x \in \text{dom}(f)$:
$$
f'_l(x):= \lim_{y\rightarrow x, y <x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}
\quad\text{and}\quad
f'_r(x):= 
\lim_{y\rightarrow x, y >x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}
$$
with possible values in $[-\infty, \infty]$.
Furthermore, for arbitrary $x,y \in \text{dom}(f)$ with $x<y$:
$$
f'_l(x)\leq f'_r(x) \leq \frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}\leq f'_l(y)\leq f'_r(y)
$$
In particular, $f'_l$ and $f'_r$ are monotonically increasing on dom$(f)$.

**Convex functions in** $\mathbb{R}^n$

Let $f:\textbf{V}\rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$ be a convex function.

For any point $\textbf{x} \in \text{dom}(f)$ and vector $\textbf{v}\in\textbf{V}$, both side direction derivatives exist, e.g.,
$$
f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v}):= \lim_{t\rightarrow 0, t>0}\frac{f(\textbf{x} + t\textbf{v}) - f(\textbf{x})}{t}\in [-\infty, \infty]
$$
Proof: This simply follows from the existence of side derivatives of convex functions on $\mathbb{R}$, applied to $\mathbb{R} \ni t \rightarrow f(\textbf{x}+t\textbf{v})$.

As a function of $\textbf{v}$, $f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v})$ is sublinear i.e.: 
\begin{align*}
f'_r(\textbf{x},\lambda\textbf{v})=&\lambda f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v}) \text{ for } \textbf{v}\in \textbf{V}, \lambda \geq 0,\\
f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v}+ \textbf{w})\leq&  f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v}) + f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{w})\\
&\text{for } \textbf{v}, \textbf{w}\in \textbf{V} \text{ with }\{f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{v}), f'_r(\textbf{x},\textbf{w})\}\neq \{-\infty, \infty\}
\end{align*}
In particular, $f'_r(\textbf{x}, \cdot)$ is also a convex function, as soon as it does not take the value $-\infty$. From the previous theorem on side derivatives follows also:
$$
f(\textbf{x})+ f'_r(\textbf{x}, \textbf{v}) \leq f(\textbf{x}+ \textbf{v})\text{ for all }\textbf{v}\in \textbf{V} \quad (1)
$$
The previous assertion, together with the definition of directional derivatives, imply that local minimizer of a convex function is also a global minimizer (2)

**My questions**

- How does the definition of the side derivatives helps to prove (1)?
- How can we conclude from that the conclusion in (2)?

Comment: There are much simpler proofs of the fact that a local minimizer of a convex function is also a global minimizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, I don't like this proof. The result doesn't need derivatives at all, and I insist on presenting an alternative proof first. I know you tagged this proof-explanation (and I will get to explaining it), but first I want to prove this properly.

Suppose $f$ is convex, and attains a local minimum at $x$. Specifically, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that if $\|y - x\| < \varepsilon$, then $f(y) \ge f(x)$.

Now, consider some $z$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$. The idea is to construct a convex combination $y$ of $z$ and $x$ so that $\|y - x\| < \varepsilon$. Then, use the local minimum property, and the standard convexity inequality. Let us take,
$$y = \lambda z + (1 - \lambda)x$$
where $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ is small enough so that $\|y - x\| < \varepsilon$. Solving,
$$\varepsilon > \|y - x\| = \|\lambda z + (1 - \lambda)x - x\| = \lambda\|z - x\|,$$
so we will choose $\lambda < \min\{1, \varepsilon / \|x - z\|\}$. The actual value of $\lambda$ doesn't matter, so long as it exists and satisfies the given requirements. Then,
\begin{align*}
f(x) \le f(y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(z) &\implies -(1 - \lambda)f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(z) \ge 0 \\
&\implies f(x) \le f(z),
\end{align*}
i.e. $f$ is a global minimum.

---

As for your actual questions,

(1) First note that, for any $t \in [0, 1]$,
\begin{align*}
f(x + v) - \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} - f(x) &= \frac{tf(x + v) - f(x + tv) + f(x) - tf(x)}{t} \\
&= \frac{tf(x + v) + (1 - t)f(x) - f(x + tv)}{t} \\
&\ge \frac{f(t(x + v) + (1 - t)x) - f(x + tv)}{t} \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, taking limits of both sides as $t \to 0^+$ (from above),
$$0 \le f(x + v) - \lim_{t \to 0^+} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t} - f(x) = f(x + v) - f'_r(x, v) - f(x),$$
which is equivalent to what you want proven.

(2) If $x$ is a local minimum, then it will have non-negative directional derivative in every direction. Thus,
$$f(x + v) \ge f'_r(x, v) + f(x) \ge 0 + f(x).$$
This holds for all $v$ (not necessarily small), hence the minimum is global.

Comment: I think $\max\{1,\varepsilon/(\lambda\|x-z\|)\}$ should actually be $\min$. And we do not really need $\lambda$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your extensive answer @Theo Bendit. I'm digesting it (and I'm a slow digester). Just for the sake of clarity: all the $\|...\|$ (norm) in your answer can be replaced by $|...|$ (absolute value) correct? Moreover regarding the second part, you wrote $(1-t)x)$, do you mean $(1-t)x$? (and please don't take me wrong: it's just to get it clear, otherwise my slow digesting brain doesn't get it)

Comment: @ecjb The norms are to be used on vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$. If $n = 1$, this will be the absolute value. If you use the absolute value brackets to denote the norm, then replacing them is fine, but the norms are there to operate on *vector* quantities like $v$ and $x$, not scalars. As for your other question, I think $(1 - t)x)$ is right, so as to line up the brackets. The whole expression there is $f\color{red}(t(x + v) + (1 - t)x\color{red})$.

Comment: regarding your first proof:
\begin{align*}
f(x) \le f(y) \quad \textbf{(1)} \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(z) \quad \textbf{(2)} &\implies -(1 - \lambda)f(x) + (1 - \lambda)f(z) \quad \textbf{(3)} \ge 0 \\
&\implies f(x) \le f(z),
\end{align*}
How do you go from (1) to (2) and from (2) to (3)?

Now regarding your second proof, how can you state the following:
$$
tf(x+v) + (1-t)f(x) = f(t(x+v) + (1-t)x)
$$

Comment: @ecjb The first one, I had $f(x) \le f(y)$ (as $x$ is a local minimum and $y$ is "close") and $f(y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(z)$ from the definition of convexity, and because $y = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda)z$. Putting these together gives $f(x) \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(z)$. Then, subtract $f(x)$ from both sides of the inequality. As for my proof explanation, I only claimed that $tf(x + v) + (1 - t)f(x) \color{red}\ge f(t(x + v) + (1 - t)x)$, not necessarily equal. This, of course, comes from the definition of convexity again (note this only works for small enough $t \le 1$).

Comment: Ok thanks again for your time @TheoBendit. I got your explanation on the second proof. (I think there is a good illustration there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality also helped). One last question (I hope): can you give me a reference for definition of convexity $f(y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(z)$ involving three variables ($x,y,z$) that I could relate to?

Comment: @ecjb Well, Jensen's inequality is only being used here in the sense that the definition of convexity, i.e. for all $x, z$, and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$, $$f(\lambda x + (1 - \lambda) z) \le \lambda f(x) + (1 - \lambda) f(z)$$ is simply the finite version of Jensen's inequality with $n = 2$. This is all I used in the second case too, with $x, y, z$, if you remember that $y$ is defined to be $$y = \lambda x + (1 - \lambda) z.$$ The inequality stated is not true if you let $x, y, z$ be independent! All I'm doing is, again, using the definition of convexity of functions, i.e. that same inequality.

Comment: @TheoBendit: one more thing: how do you know that $\frac{f(t(x+v)+(1-t)x) - f(x-tv)}{t} = 0$ ?

Comment: @ecjb It's $$\frac{f(t(x + v) + (1 - t)x) - f(x \color{red}+tv)}{t} = 0.$$It's true simply from expanding the brackets inside the first $f$ term.